# Access data from actions inside of components | Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'd like to get my navbar to display the user's name that I'm getting from my API. And I can see in my console that I'm getting the `user object` with the key `name`.

So I wonder what's the best practice to get access to the data?
Here's some snippets from my navbar by the way!

```
class MainNavbar extends Component {
  logout(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.logout()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <div>
              <img id="logo" />
            </div>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
```

And at the bottom:

```
MainNavbar.propTypes = {
  logout: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  // I guess I need to do something here
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
    // And here as well, but what? :O
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(MainNavbar)
```

Thanks a lot for reading this bad and nooby question. I appreciate all the help I can get!

Thanks!

Comment: @AndyRay That's not true at all. Sure, not accepting answers is bad (please accept answers you've found helpful as a checkpoint for future readers) but it won't result in your account be 'closed' whatever that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map the user name from the redux state into the component's props, you'll need to:

Add it to the propTypes.

```
MainNavbar.propTypes = {
    logout: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    name: React.PropTypes.string
}
```

Map the new prop from the redux state.
You'll need to check that this correctly maps from your state

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
    name: state.user.name
  }
}
```

Conditionally display the name in your component.

```
<Navbar.Header>
  <Navbar.Brand>
    <div>
      <img id="logo" alt="Qlocx Logo" src={qlocx} />
    </div>
  </Navbar.Brand>
  {this.props.name ? this.props.name : null}
  <Navbar.Toggle />
```

Comment: Yes, OP didn't post the whole redux store, which is why I wrote "You'll need to check that this correctly maps from your state"

Comment: Thanks for replying man! I like your name btw, but that didn't do the trick! :(

Comment: Hi @Martin do you have the path to the user name in your redux store? Also, how you're accessing the prop inside the component's `render()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You may need `<Provider store>` , then you can use Redux store in the component.

> https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store

Comment: Hello, I have provided my store.

Comment: Maybe,add `const {auth} = this.props` before return in render() ,then you can use like this.<div>{auth}</div>